# BCS Incremental crawl running longer than full crawl in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, bcs, crawl, incremental-crawl

We have configured BCS search in SharePoint 2016. Created External content type with Sharepoint Designer and created Content Source using with External content type.(Source in Documentum).
While run Full crawl, completed less than 3 hours and got errors. Again we ran Incremental crawl, errors were disappeared, but incremental crawl is running forever until We stopped incremental crawl.[image: Bcs]

Please help us to resolve this issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does your BCS ECT support incremental crawling?

Comment: Hi Matthew,
Thanks for reply. Actually I have no idea, how to check either BCS ECT support incremental crawling or not.

Comment: The person who created the ECT should know. If they don't then it is unlikely that incremental crawling is supported.

Comment: I think they are not configure ECT to support Incremental Crawling, could you please advice how to do

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create supply the LastModifiedTimeStampField property on the Finder Method Instance and point it at the property of you External Content Type's last modified timestamp field. This will be used for incremental crawling.

```
<Property Name="LastModifiedTimeStampField" Type="System.String">LastModified</Property>
```

More Info [Developing for BCS](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/enhancing-the-bdc-model-file-for-search-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Hi Matthew,
I have tried with that property, but no luck
<MethodInstance Type="Finder" ReturnParameterName="Read List" Default="true" Name="Read List" DefaultDisplayName="Simon_In_Test Read List">
                  <Properties>
                    <Property Name="LastModifiedTimeStampField" Type="System.String">Modified_date</Property>
                    <Property Name="RootFinder" Type="System.String"></Property>
                    <Property Name="UseClientCachingForSearch" Type="System.String"></Property> </Properties>

Comment: Is Modified_date returned in your query?

Comment: Finally we got to work that we need to add
<Property Name="LastModifiedTimeStampField" Type="System.String">LastModified</Property>

in Specific Finder Method Read Item

Comment: Yes, glad you got it working. Can you mark the answer?